# what is the difference between opencv's and matlab's bicubic algorithm?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, image-resizing

When using opencv's resize

```
img = cv2.imread('fname.png', 0 )
res = cv2.resize(img,None,fx=2, fy=2, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
cv2.imwrite('scaled_cv2.png',res)
```

and matlab's imresize

```
I = imread('fname.png');
J = imresize(I,2, 'Antialiasing', false, 'Method', 'bicubic');
imwrite(J,'scaled_matlab.png')
```

and comparing with imagemagick's compare with

```
compare -metric PSNR fname.png scaled_cv2.png diff_cv2.png
compare -metric PSNR fname.png scaled_matlab.png diff_matlab.png
```

I get completely different PSNR values
What are they doing different?

Comment: I refer readers to these discussions regarding difference between MATLAB's `imresize` and OpenCV `cv::resize` with the bicubic interpolation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26812289/97160, http://stackoverflow.com/q/26823140/97160 . It turns out those two implementations use a different value for a free parameter involved in the cubic function...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Matlab's doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html):

> `'bicubic'`
>
> Bicubic interpolation (the default); the output pixel value is a weighted average of pixels in the nearest 4-by-4 neighborhood

And from [OpenCV's doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize):

> `INTER_CUBIC` - a bicubic interpolation over 4x4 pixel neighborhood

So the only explanation for this is that they use **different weighting strategy** to get the average value.

From Matlab imresize.m source, you can find that the **kernel constant A** (see [Bicubic interpolation on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation)) is set to **-0.5**, whereas it is set to **-0.75** in OpenCV (see imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, function interpolateCubic() [on github for instance](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp)).

This gives different kernel shapes for the convolution :
[image: difference between Matlab (a=-0.5) and OpenCV (a=-0.75) Kernels for bicubic interpolation]

Therefore, you will end with slightly different results in the final interpolated image; typically more [ringing artifacts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts) and overshoot for OpenCV, but also sharper edges and a better [PSNR](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_Signal_to_Noise_Ratio) compared with the "true" underlying high-resolution image.

Comment: How those different weighting strategies differ? What does opencv use? I guess that one can perform cubic interpolation quite differently, but what's the catch? Why don't they use the same algorithm (imagemagick, opencv, matlab, pil, etc.)?

Comment: @Piclem Thanks for your editing to make it clear. :P

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to different affine transformations from the output pixels to the input pixels. Check [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14560/understanding-matlab-mathematicas-bilinear-interpolation/14566#14566) on `'blinear'` counter-intuition example. Besides, in [another post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42825/understanding-bilinear-imageresize/42842?noredirect=1#42842), a hypothesis on the interpolation domain (`[1,n]` vs `[0,n]`) is verified on Mathematica, also with `'bilinear'` method. So I guess it is the similar reason that causes such a difference between Matlab and OpenCV.