# MATLAB vs C++ vs OpenCV - imresize

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing, interpolation

I have the following MATLAB code which I want to transport into C++

Assume `Gr` is 2d matrix and `1/newscale == 0.5`

```
Gr = imresize(Gr, 1 / newScale);
```

in [the MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html?refresh=true):

> B = imresize(A, scale) returns image B that is scale times the size of
>   A. The input image A can be a grayscale, RGB, or binary image. If
>   scale is between 0 and 1.0, B is smaller than A. If scale is greater
>   than 1.0, B is larger than A.

So this means I will get a 2D matrix  == matrix_width/2 and matrix_height/2 
How do I calculate the values? The default according to the docs are coming from cubic interpolation for nearest 4X4.

I can't find a sample code for C++ that does the same. Can you please provide a link to such code?

I also found [this OpenCV function, `resize`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?#void%20cvResize(const%20CvArr*%20src,%20CvArr*%20dst,%20int%20interpolation)).

Does it do the same as the MATLAB one?

Comment: according to the MATLAB docs, `bicubic` is the default interpolation method. If you want to get the same in OpenCV, specify `INTER_CUBIC` in `resize` function

Comment: @Amro you also have to turn off anti-aliasing to match OpenCV

Comment: ah, good observation

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22092744/97160

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, just be aware that MATLAB's [`imresize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) has [anti-aliasing enabled by default](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/resizing-an-image.html#f12-24819):

```
imresize(A,scale,'bilinear')
```

vs. what you would get with `cv::resize()`, which does not have anti-aliasing:

```
imresize(A,scale,'bilinear','AntiAliasing',false)
```

And as Amro mentioned, the default in MATLAB is `bicubic`, so be sure to specify.

### Bilinear

No code modifications are necessary to get matching results with bilinear interpolation.

Example OpenCV snippet:

```
cv::Mat src(4, 4, CV_32F);
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    src.at<float>(i) = i;

std::cout << src << std::endl;

cv::Mat dst;
cv::resize(src, dst, Size(0, 0), 0.5, 0.5, INTER_LINEAR);

std::cout << dst << std::endl;
```

**Output (OpenCV)**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3;
  4, 5, 6, 7;
  8, 9, 10, 11;
  12, 13, 14, 15]

[2.5, 4.5;
  10.5, 12.5]
```

**MATLAB**

```
>> M = reshape(0:15,4,4).';
>> imresize(M,0.5,'bilinear','AntiAliasing',true)
ans =
                     3.125                     4.875
                    10.125                    11.875
>> imresize(M,0.5,'bilinear','AntiAliasing',false)
ans =
                       2.5                       4.5
                      10.5                      12.5
```

Note that the results are the same with anti-aliasing turned off.

### Bicubic Difference

However, between `'bicubic'` and `INTER_CUBIC`, the results are different on account of the weighting scheme!  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26823261/2778484) for details on the mathematical difference.  The issue is in the `interpolateCubic()` function that computes the cubic interpolant's coefficients, where a constant of `a = -0.75` is used rather than `a = -0.5` like in MATLAB.  However, if you edit imgwarp.cpp and change the code :

```
static inline void interpolateCubic( float x, float* coeffs )
{
    const float A = -0.75f;
    ...
```

to:

```
static inline void interpolateCubic( float x, float* coeffs )
{
    const float A = -0.50f;
    ...
```

and rebuild OpenCV (tip: disable CUDA and the gpu module for short compile time), then you get the same results:

**MATLAB**

```
>> imresize(M,0.5,'bicubic','AntiAliasing',false)
ans =
                    2.1875                    4.3125
                   10.6875                   12.8125
```

**OpenCV**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3;
  4, 5, 6, 7;
  8, 9, 10, 11;
  12, 13, 14, 15]
[2.1875, 4.3125;
  10.6875, 12.8125]
```

More about cubic [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26823140/2778484).

Comment: I need something bit exact so should i just try to implement it on my own ?

Comment: @Gilad For bilinear, just use OpenCV.  For bicubic, I guess you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: the results in bicubic are not even close. can you suggest a place to start looking for c++ implmentation like matlab for that?

Comment: This was one of my biggest gotchas when switching between OpenCV and MATLAB.  Darn anti-aliasing!  Your previous post saved me about a month ago.  Thanks btw!

Comment: @rayryeng With cubic, modifications to imgwarp.cpp in OpenCV are necessary to get matching results.  [Amro and I have been hammering away](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26823140/2778484) at the issue to our own amusement. :)

Comment: @chappjc so I think all that is left for me is to decide what do i do now? change the opencv implementation which will suite me, or try to implement imresize.I might need the regular openCV for something else. although I might just copy some code from there. it is opensource after all..

Comment: @Gilad Yeah, open under the BSD license, which is extremely permissive.  You can also grab cubic interpolation code from somewhere else and verify that it uses the same constant and the equations work out the same way.  For example, you can change the equation in the paulinternet.nl implementation of `cubicInterpolate` you found to correspond the the correct coefficient.  (that function combined the coeffs and the summation).

Comment: @chappjc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851389/opencv-image-resize-comparison-to-matlab can you have a look here?

Answer (score 3):

In OpenCV, the call would be:

```
cv::Mat dst;
cv::resize(src, dst, Size(0,0), 0.5, 0.5, INTER_CUBIC);
```

You might then have to do some smoothing/blurring to emulate the anti-aliasing which MATLAB also performs by default (see [@chappjc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26812346/97160)'s answer)

Comment: a related post about MATLAB's `imresize`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7759981/97160 (also check out the linked posts)

Comment: I updated my post with an example using `bilinear`, but I'm not able to get identical results with `bicubic` regardless of the anti-aliasing setting. Do you know what's the deal with that?  Wait... just saw [your link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22093004/2778484).  That explains it!

Comment: @Amro can you have a look here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851389/opencv-image-resize-comparison-to-matlab