# Matlab filter2 and opencv sobel produce different image gradients

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, gradient, sobel

I need to implement histogram of oriented gradients for patches in an image (one HOG feature vector per patch, not one HOG for the whole image). I have been using the Matlab code at [this link](https://github.com/chrisjmccormick/hog_matlab) and translating the code to opencv python. I have made some changes to fit it for my purpose, one of the main difference between the Matlab and Python codes is in the way I get the gradient of each cell, while in Matlab I am using *filter2* as was used in the above link, in Opencv I use *Sobel* operator. My problem is that the gradients that these two methods produce are different and I had a hard time fixing it. I tried changing both the image and kernel numerical representations. I also tried using *filter2D* in opencv, also *imfilter* in Matlab, but basically none of them worked. Here is the Matlab code for calculating the gradient using *filter2*:

```
blockSize=26;
cellSize=floor(blockSize/2);
cellPerBlock=4;
numBins=9;
dim = [444,262];
RGB = imread('testImage.jpg');
img= rgb2gray(RGB);

img = imresize(img, [262,444], 'bilinear', 'Antialiasing',false);

%operators 
hx = [-1,0,1];
hy = [-1;0;1] ;

%derivatives 
dx = filter2(hx, double(img));
dy = filter2(hy, double(img));

% Remove the 1 pixel border.
dx = dx(2 : (size(dx, 1) - 1), 2 : (size(dx, 2) - 1));
dy = dy(2 : (size(dy, 1) - 1), 2 : (size(dy, 2) - 1)); 

% Convert the gradient vectors to polar coordinates (angle and magnitude).
ang = atan2(dy, dx);
ang(ang < 0) = ang(ang < 0)+ pi;
mag = ((dy.^2) + (dx.^2)).^.5;
```

And this is the Python OpenCV version that I wrote using *Sobel* operator:

```
blockSize=26
cellSize=int(blockSize/2)
cellPerBlock=4
numBins=9
dim = (444,262)
angDiff=10**-6
img = cv2.imread('3132 2016-04-25 12-35-43-53991.jpg',0)
img = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img.astype(float),cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=1)
sobelx = sobelx[1 : np.shape(sobelx)[0] - 1, 1 : np.shape(sobelx)[1] - 1]

sobely = cv2.Sobel(img.astype(float),cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=1)
sobely = sobely[1 : np.shape(sobely)[0] - 1, 1 : np.shape(sobely)[1] - 1]

mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(sobelx, sobely)
ang[ang>np.pi+angDiff]= ang[ang>np.pi+angDiff] - np.pi
```

**Edit:** I have followed the post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812289/matlab-vs-c-vs-opencv-imresize), using bilinear method in Matlab and cv2.INTER_LINEAR in OpenCV, as well as deactivating Antialiasing in Matlab, but still the two resized images do not exactly match. Here is a part of the resized image for a test image in Matlab:
[image]

And this is the same part from OpenCV:
[image]

**2nd Edit:** It turns out the way rounding happens causes this difference. So, I changed my OpenCV code to :

```
img = cv2.resize(img.astype(float), dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

and the Matlab:

```
imresize(double(img), [262,444], 'bilinear', 'Antialiasing',false);
```

And now both give me the same result.
[image]

I think the problem is caused by the derivative methods. I have checked cv2.filter2D in OpenCV, but still the results are different. I hope someone can give me a hint on what possibly could have caused the problem.

Comment: The most likely culprit is the image resizing.  Note that `imresize` in MATLAB and `cv2.resize` in OpenCV resize the images differently - just because you choose bicubic or bilinear interpolation between them both doesn't mean you will get the same results.  Specifically, MATLAB enables anti-aliasing by default where OpenCV does not.  Please refer to the duplicate to ensure that how you are resizing the images between both environments is the same.  By default, MATLAB uses bicubic interpolation which you are doing here.  `cv2.INTER_AREA` does not do bicubic interpolation but another method.

Comment: Make sure that the resized image between both platforms give you the same pixels for each location. Even just changing to cubic doesn't solve your problem. If you suspect that the Sobel filter is the problem, use `cv2.filter2D` to match the `filter2` in MATLAB. This boils down to a step by step line trace between both programs. Find where exactly they differ at what line, then determine the reason why. There's nothing more I can say beyond this.

Comment: I have edited my code, deactivating the antialiasing and matching the interpolation methods. However, there is still difference between the results. I have also, checked cv2.filter2D, but that doesn't help either. I hope you can remove the duplicate mark on this question as the problem still exits, even though the resize methods now are the same.

Comment: I'm not going to unless you can tell us where exactly it's different. You have not confirmed to me that the interpolation methods between the two frameworks give exactly the same output pixel wise.

Comment: I hope now you can remove the duplicate mark. My answers from the imresize are now the same in Matlab and Python, but when I take the derivative the results are different and using filter2D couldn't help either. The other reason it is not the duplicate of the linked question is that I had to change the numerical representation of the images in order for their resize outputs to match, while the other question is not concerned with this issue.

Comment: OK. I'll reopen. I can't look at your question fully now but I will when I get home. I suspect you're right about the derivatives.