# MATLAB imwarp vs C++ warpAffine

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I am trying to convert following MATLAB code into c++ code by Opencv library

**Matlab Code:**

```
scale_x = 0.99951;
scale_y = 0.99951;
RsrcImg= imref2d(size(im1));
T=[scale_x 0 0;0 scale_y 0;0 0 1];
tformEstimate = affine2d(T);
destImg =imwarp(im1,tformEstimate,'Interp','cubic','OutputView',RsrcImg);
```

**C++ Code:**

```
double scale_x = 0.99951;
double scale_y = 0.99951;
Mat tformEstimate=Mat::zeros(2,3,CV_64FC1);
tformEstimate.at<double>(0,0)=scale_x;
tformEstimate.at<double>(1,1)=scale_y;
warpAffine(im1,destImg,tformEstimate,im1.size(),INTER_CUBIC);
```

but I get completely different PSNR values! is there any way to make both codes work with the same result?

**INPUT:**

```
im1=[19656,20452,21048,21020,20564;
20740,21332,21964,20932,20220;
21688,21832,20236,21520,21948;
19780,20572,21056,20748,20088;
20560,21188,20608,22136,20736]
```

**Matlab output:**

```
[19656.4613056001,20452.8984647534,21048.6416903208,21019.5009522438,0;
20741.1425789163,21333.2772155087,21963.2997618553,20930.5373907996,0; 
21687.3205560205,21830.7204384573,20235.1172001277,21521.5360776160,0;
19779.1003189859,20572.0033036149,21056.4880106032,20747.6616956745,0;
0,0,0,0,0]
```

**C++ output:**

```
[19656.00000  20452.00000  21048.00000  21020.00000  20564.00000  
20740.00000  21332.00000  21964.00000  20932.00000  20220.00000  
21688.00000  21832.00000  20236.00000  21520.00000  21948.00000  
19780.00000  20572.00000  21056.00000  20748.00000  20088.00000  
20560.00000  21188.00000  20608.00000  22136.00000  20736.00000]
```

I have seen 
[MATLAB vs C++ vs OpenCV - imresize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812289/matlab-vs-c-vs-opencv-imresize)
 without success.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: find out what kind of interpolation is used in matlabs imwarp

Comment: do both results look similar? Is the result size equal?

Comment: @Micka  cubic interpolation is used in matlab, the result size is equal,and  first rows look similar, but last rows not

Comment: @Micka , I improve my post

Comment: why are matlabs last row and column zero?

Comment: looks like different border interpolation?

Comment: `Matlab: 'FillValues' — Value used for output pixels outside image boundaries
numeric scalar or array
Value used for output pixels outside the input image boundaries, specified as the comma-separated pair consisting of 'FillValues' and a numeric array. Fill values are used for output pixels when the corresponding inverse transformed location in the input image is completely outside the input image boundaries.

If the input image is 2-D, FillValues must be a scalar.`

Comment: Opencv: `borderMode – pixel extrapolation method (see borderInterpolate()); when
borderMode=BORDER_TRANSPARENT , it means that the pixels in the destination image corresponding
to the “outliers” in the source image are not modified by the function.
borderValue – value used in case of a constant border; by default, it is 0.`